# How to fix qt designer after it stopped working suddenly?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt-designer

At some point, qt designer stopped opening.

Everything used to work fine.

Reinstalling didn't help.

I found a solution for "deleting files" on the Internet, but there are no such files in the system.

An attempt to reinstall via pycharm did not work, as did an attempt to install qt designer separately.

Comment: You should provide more details about "deleting files" solution (what files are these, where did you find this solution...etc), and the last thing you were doing before it stopped working, it could be helpful to others in the future who stumble upon this post.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by installing python 3.8 and installing PySide2. qt designer will be called from PySide2.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).